# Error converting DateTime to string format yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to convert some DateTime values to string format `yyyy-MM-dd`. The problem is i only need the date but in my case `model.StartDate` contains both date and time. When declaring model.StartDate as string "start" looks like this: `4/1/2014 12:00:00 AM`. I get this error when trying to parse:

> System.FormatException was unhandled by user code Message=String was
>   not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My best guess is that the error occurs because string contains both Date and Time but i could be wrong. If i explore model.StartDate further i can also find Day, DayOfTheWeek etc. Is this the right approach? I just want to convert `model.StartDate` to string "start" with format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Heres my code:

```
string start = model.StartDate.ToString();
model.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string end = model.EndDate.ToString();
model.EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(end, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Dunno what the problem is, might be that start contains time? I have no idea.

The model.StartDate and model.EndDate are DateTime properties from the view model:

```
        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.GAStatistics.GAStatistics.StartDate")]
        [UIHint("DateNullable")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.GAStatistics.GAStatistics.EndDate")]
        [UIHint("DateNullable")]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

EDIT:
Iv'e uploaded a image here showing the actual output i'm getting in the debugger:
https://imageshack.com/i/1n51u2p

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for that, images removed.

Comment: If you rely on a certain format when parsing, you also need the serialization (ToString) to produce that format. ToString takes parameters to define the format, see @Panagiotis' answer

Comment: I think what is important here is the Type of `model.StartDate` is this a `DateTime` or a `String`? In your model, this should ideally be a DateTime so that you can format it however you want in your UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting the dates to string but you don't specify the format. Try

```
string start = model.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd);
```

`ToString()` uses the current thread's Culture format to convert the date to a string, including the time. The format used is `G`, the general date and time format.

Just for this format, you don't need to specify CultureInfo.InvariantCulture because there isn't anything culture specific. A common gotcha with the `yyyy/MM/dd` format though is that some cultures use `-` as the date specifier, and `/` is the date placeholder. In such a case you would have to use:

```
string start = model.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**UPDATE**

From the comments, it seems that `model.StartDate` and `model.EndDate` are *not* DateTime objects but strings with a specific format that include a time element.

What you are actually trying to do is parse the original string to a DateTime object, then format this object to the new format string:

```
var date=DateTime.ParseExact(model.StartDate,"M/d/YYYY HH:mm:ss tt",
         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
model.StartDate=date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

assuming the string the value "4/1/2014 12:00:00 AM" for April 1, 2014

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying about culture specific. Well i tried - string start = model.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd); - but the i get: No overolad method for"Tostring"takes 1 arguments. All i want to do is to take the date from model.StartDate, convert it to a string with format "yyyy-MM-dd". The reason for this is i this format is needed when sending requests to Google Analytics API

Comment: This can only happen if model.StartDate is NOT a DateTime. [DateTime.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) is available since .NET 2.0. What is the type of `model.StartDate`? If it's a string, what are its contents?

Comment: Ive updated the post showing the view model and the DateTime properties for StartDate and EndDate. I uploaded an image here, meaby it will clarify the situation: https://imageshack.com/i/1n51u2p Thank you!

Comment: A `DateTime?` is not a `DateTime` but an alias for `Nullable<DateTime>`. To get the actual value you have to write model.StartDate.Value

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem for now. Removed "?" from the model properties and wrote this:  string start = model.StartDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            model.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be misunderstanding how [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) works (or actually what it does). Parsing, in general, is the process of taking data of type X and converting it to type Y - in the context of `DateTime` this means converting a date `string` to a `DateTime` instance. This is *completely* different to what you are trying to do which is *formatting* a `DateTime` instance.

Given you already have the date you don't need to parse anything, all you need to do is *format* the date

```
model.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is important when working with fixed formats because you want to make sure you aren't culture aware i.e. the format you specify is *exactly* how you want it to display in all cultures.

Comment: Can't see what InvariantCulture offers here. Nothing in this format is culture specific. If it was "yyyy/MM/dd" you could have some issues with cultures that use `-` as the date separator

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I never said it was specifically for this format I said it's important when working with fixed formats. Regardless, I do it as a general rule of thumb because nothing is set in stone...

Comment: Thanks for explaining about parsing. Sorry if i missunderstand you but StartDate is a DateTime property from my ViewModel. If i say - string Start = model.StartDate.ToString(); "start" will have the same value as "model.StartDate" but in string format. However this format is "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss". I need to remove the time and just format the date to be yyyy-MM-dd. For eg 2014-04-01 instead of "4/1/2014 14:46:57 AM"

Comment: @KristofferAndersson yes, if you just call **ToString()** - if you call it as I have shown you in my answer you are *formatting* the result in such a way that you only take the date. `ToString` has various overloads, one of which allows you to pass in a format parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `.Date` property of a DateTime to get only the Date part. Your ToString() will also yield different results based on the current culture meaning that while your ToString() and then TryParse might work for you right now, it will break in other countries.

You can use ToString() overload to specify a specific format. Different formats can be found [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Comment: I see but i cant access .Date or i'm doing it wrong. Do i need to create a new DateTime variable or can i write model.StartDate.Date? The date values come from a DatePicker in a View using a view model and model.StartDate is a DateTime property from that model.

Comment: This still won't convert to a specific format, only to the thread's current date format. For most locales, this is *not* `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: The code makes it look like the OP does not want to format to a string but get a Date without a Time part.

Comment: Actually the code tries to demonstrate that converting to string fails

Comment: @Laoujin you can format a `DateTime` as `yyyy-MM-dd` without the `Date` property...

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` returns a DateTime. I'm guessing that `model.StartDate` is a DateTime, not a String. (Otherwise it would be an compile time error)

Comment: @Kristoffer: A DateTime is designed so that any operation returns a new DateTime automatically. So accessing the `.Date` property returns a new DateTime. But yes, accessing `model.StartDate.Date` would do what you want.

Comment: @Laoujin: Ok. Well i tried this: - string start = model.StartDate.Date; - but it tells me there's no definition for "Date". .Date was the first thing i looked up but i didn't get it to work in my code